# ValueError works but prevents code from running

Tags: python, valueerror

I can get the program to count properly and I can get the program to not except float and strings but when i put the two pieces of code together the program won't run the count. Thanks for the help.

```
print("\tProgram counts the number of positive integers.")

def numCount():

    even_count = 0
    odd_count = 0
    even_sum = 0
    odd_sum = 0
    total = 0

    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input("Input an integer to count 0 exits program: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer.")
            continue
        else:
            return num                 
        if num == 0:
            break
        elif num < 1:
            continue
        elif num % 2 == 0:
            even_count += 1
            even_sum += num
        else:
            odd_count += 1
            odd_sum += num
        total += 1
    print("\nTotal positive intger count is:", total)
numCount()
```

Comment: What error are you getting/issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove:

```py
else:
   return num
```

This is because `return` will exit the function early and stop the `while` loop from continuing.

Comment: `return` does not "need" to be used anywhere, and certainly is NOT needed  inside a method. If the `except` did not throw an error a return might be reasonable for some solution.

Comment: Still does not answer the question as to why the script is not running correctly, as the return statement is indeed already in a function.  The actual reason he should remove the return statement is that it is just incorrectly placed/should not be there from the first place

Comment: Apologies.   When i viewed this originally not all the code was in the code block.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not return `num` in the `else` statement of the try/except. This will immediately exit the function and return the current value of `num`, instead of it continuing to be processed in the rest of your code.

To fix this, you can simply remove the `else` statement.